# Coercion Failed: Input cannot be null for this coercion - Dynamic Approvers for SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I'm trying to set a dynamic workflow of approvers for a SharePoint workflow. The template was originally from Sharepoint 2010.

I'm trying to do it as such that if a user selects certain criteria on the form, the template will route the request to another manager based on that selection. Here's the code. [image] Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you set the user in your task assignment, how are you telling the workflow to deliver the value? Try setting it as a string if it isn't set that way already. See screenshot.

[image]

Cheers,

-Drew